# helm-show-kill-ring disregards the selection

Tags: helm, yank, kill-ring

When I select entries (with `C-<SPACE>`) in `helm-show-kill-ring` and press either `Enter` or `F1`, it disregards the selection and yanks the entry currently under cursor. Why would this be the case and how can I cause it to yank all the selected entries?

Versions: Emacs 24.5.1, helm-20150626.731

Comment: Not sure about a such old version of Helm, it's nearly 2018. Can you upgrade your Helm and try again? By the way, It works fine with helm-20171218.2053 from here.

Comment: The discussion of this question has been moved to https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1934